# cakephp 3 share component and controllers attribute (plugin)

Tags: plugins, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to understand how I can utilize controllers in component, when they are the parts of the same plugin. And I am not quite sure if it is a good practice to do so.

To register any controllers from where the component is called I use:

```
  public function setController($controller)
{
    $this->Controller = $controller;
}

public function initialize(array $config)
{
  parent::initialize($config);
  $this->Controller = $this->_registry->getController();
}
```

But when I want to use controller that belongs to the plugin package, what is the proper way?

Comment: I don't get the actual problem, a component always receives the instance of the controller where it is attached to, so if it's a controller that belongs to a plugin, then you'll an instance of that plugin controller? Also why would you need to set any other controller than the one where the component is attached to?

Comment: I am trying to follow the tutorial from the Cook Book http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html. There is a passage when ContactsController is being created. The thing is I cannot see how to call this controller through the component instance $this->ContactManager->Contact->function()? While in the component I use setController.

Comment: You simply do not call a controller other than the one the component is currently attached to, working with multiple controllers at the same time violates the MVC principle, and the need to do that indicates bad application design. Again, I don't understand _why_ you would want to do that, in order to receive a helpful answer from anyone, it would probably be good if you'd come up with a real world example.

Comment: I understand how to utilize a component by calling (via the example) $this->ContactManager->foo(); And I know how to utilize components from the controllers by initializing $this->controller in component. But only thing I really don't understand, how I can use controller that is a part of the plugin, beside a reference in plugin/routes.php. Could you show an example how to use the ContactsController with its component http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-controllers

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get your problem. I have no clue what exactly you are doing there, why you are doing it, and how this is a problem exclusive to plugin controllers. Again, please come up with a real world example, code that shows what exactly you want to call where exactly, and why exactly.

Comment: ok. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/5LNY0sxA, I skipped the views/models. I understand it may be not according to the MVC principles, but how to use ContactController, that renders a specific view with some additional data from Model, and it should be included in foo() of Component? Is that just overkill?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89292/discussion-between-pt0-and-ndm).